# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect when we download java client application from Java web Start

Tags: java, java-web-start, connectexception

Our Java Client Appllication(Java Swing Application) is downloaded by java web start.At that time its throw following exception.

I have following questions.

1. What is reason for this exception?
2. is this because of client code or Firewall(windows and internet)?
3. If I set java control panel->Network settings and check direct connection its working fine. if its "use browser setting" this exception fired.But some machines with "use browser setting" its working fine.

Does anyone have any idea?

Our Java Client Application (Java Swing Application) is downloaded by Java Web Start. At that time it's throw following exception.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.getJSFileFromURL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.retrieveContentOfPACFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.contructLegacyPACScript_16(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.init(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.SunAutoProxyHandler.init(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.reset(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.reset(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.initializeExecutionEnvironment(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.isSupportedINSFile(Unknown Source)

I have following questions.

1.What is reason for this exception?

2.is this because of client code or Firewall(windows and internet)?

3.If i set java control panel->Network settings and check direct connection its working fine. if its "use browser setting" this exception fired.But some machines with "use browser setting" its working fine.

Does anyone have any idea?
```